# Weak Ciphers Detected

Tags: security, encryption, registry

After running a vulnerability scan on my application, the Netsparker returned a Weak Ciphers issue.

The resolution tells me to modify the registry like so:

> • click Run, type regedt32 or type regedit, and then click OK.
>
> • In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key :
>   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders
>
> • Set "Enabled" DWORD to "0x0" for the following registry keys:
>
> SCHANNEL\Ciphers\DES 56/56
>
> SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 64/128
>
> SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 40/128
>
> SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC2 56/128
>
> SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC2 40/128
>
> SCHANNEL\Ciphers\NULL
>
> SCHANNEL\Hashes\MD5

But when I go to Ciphers, all I see is "Default".

Am I missing something? How to correct this problem?

Comment: This seems.more like an admin question to me.

Comment: What Netspaker edition do you use?

Comment: @menjaraz - i don't see a version number of anything on it. I just get the pdf with the results from our web team...

Comment: There are 3 editions of Netsparker: the community edition is the stripped off free one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the time configuration settings have default values; if they are not present you will have to create them.

Comment: @xrum yes, you'll have to create them if they don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

RC4 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) or ARCFOUR and some other ciphers are considered as weak ciphers because there are known vulnerability found with those crypto algorithms.
All it means is that, it is asking you to disable those ciphers. Microsoft provides guidelines for doing so http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245030. Again it all depends upon your threat analysis or modeling. You read upon threat modeling and then decide if you want to do so, otherwise you can do it anyway.